# Does RSA encrpytion work for small numbers?

Tags: math, rsa, private-key

Suppose:

```
p = 3
q = 11
n = 33
phi = 20
e = 7
d = 3
```

If I want to encrypt the number 123, I would do `(123^7) % 33`, which equals`18`.
Now if I want to decrypt `18`, I do `(18^3) % 33`, which gives me `24`.
As you can see, the input number and decrypted number is not the same. Does anyone know why this is? Also does this mean I have to break the number `123` up into single digits and then encrypt `1`, `2` and `3` separately?

EDIT: I am aware that due to the value of `n`, anything I `mod` by `n` would be lower than `n`. Does that mean I have to intially choose very large numbers for `p` and `q`?

Comment: If your number to be encrypted is larger than `n`, you can write in base-n and you encrypt it's (base-n) digits separately.

Answer (score 4):

From [the Wikipedia page for RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29#Encryption) (my emphasis):

> Bob then wishes to send message M to Alice.
>
> He first turns `M` into an integer `m`, **such that `0 <= m < n`** by using an
>   agreed-upon reversible protocol known as a padding scheme. He then
>   computes the ciphertext c corresponding to
>
> ```
> c = m^e (mod n)
> ```

Your `m` (`123`) is **not** less than `n` (`33`), so it doesn't work. So yes, you would need to start with larger `p` and `q` to get a larger `n`.